# Outline in css not working in IE (latest ver)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, focus, outline

Currently working in UI of my web design. I have noticed that the outlined in my div does not display in IEv11?

Here in my css...

```css
.samp-banner:focus, #samp-banner-id:focus,
#samp-close:focus, #samp-close-mobile:focus {
    outline: #c0dffb auto 1px;
}

.samp-banner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #d4edda;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="samp-banner" tabindex="0">sample</div>
```

Update: I have tried adding !important still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `outline-style: auto` in your css, it means that it's up to the browser to decide what to do based on the context of the element. Webkit renders `outline-style: auto` differently than other browsers. If you want to get behavior that's more similar across browsers I'd recommend you use below code or `box-shadow` instead.

```css
.samp-banner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  padding: 10px;
}

.samp-banner:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #c0dffb;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="samp-banner">sample</dov>
```

Comment: Still not working on my end. Also, the outline-offset is not readable in IE. not sure if this is a version issue

Comment: looks like ie11 as a partial support to `outline` property https://caniuse.com/#feat=outline, a i have said in my answer use `box-shadow`

Answer (score 1):

replace

> "outline: #c0dffb auto 1px;"

with

> outline: #c0dffb solid 1px;